# Android Activity life cycle issues

Tags: android, android-activity

**What I actually Wanted ?**

In my app I have 4/5 activities and one background thread which talks with the server. I wanted to have some way to get the top most activity of my app. But surprisingly their was no way I could get that ?

**What I did ?**

After searching for a while, I implemented a variable `mCurrentOnTopActivity` of Type `Activity` and on `onResume()` and `onPause()` of every activity I set that variable. (That is actually a bad way).

**Where I reached ?**

Now their are cases in which after receiving some messages from the server I want to do some thing on UI thread i.e. show some dialogs or refresh `ListView`, now their is no way to check whether the `mCurrentOnTopActivity` refers an activiy which is actually running or not (finished or out Of focus for whatever reason).

*What I want now ?*
Now I basically want help in following two problems:-

1. How do I know which is the currently running top most activity of my App ?
2. How do I know whether activity is still running or not (i.e. I want some thing like `isActicitAlive() (imaginary function)` which returns true between calls of `onResume()` and `onPause()` ?

I implemented 2 point using a variable in activity and setting it in `onResume()` and `onPause()`. But, is this the only way to do this ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
ArrayList<String> runningactivities = new ArrayList<String>();

ActivityManager activityManager = (ActivityManager)getBaseContext().getSystemService (Context.ACTIVITY_SERVICE); 

List<RunningTaskInfo> services = activityManager.getRunningTasks(Integer.MAX_VALUE); 

for (int i1 = 0; i1 < services.size(); i1++) { 
    runningactivities.add(0,services.get(i1).topActivity.toString());  
} 

if(runningactivities.contains("ComponentInfo{com.app/com.app.main.MyActivity}")==true){
    Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(),"Activity is in foreground, active",1000).show(); 
}
```

With this, you can check, whether the activity you are looking for is running or not.

esle, if you want to use the `onStart()` and `onStop()` methods, you can use the following code,

```
class MyActivity extends Activity {
     static boolean active = false;

      @Override
      public void onStart() {
         super.onStart();
         active = true;
      } 

      @Override
      public void onStop() {
         super.onStop();
         active = false;
      }
}
```

Comment: I am currently using the second approach of your answer. Let me check the efficiency perspective of your first approach. Querying ActivityManager every now and than doesn't sounds efficient, at least to me... Any ways thanks  for your answer.

Comment: I ended implementing the option you suggested after some changes.. Thanks!!

Comment: @Amit:- :) which one.? first or second approach.?

Comment: the second one.. As I found that really extensible.. i created AnActivity with these methods and all my other activities extend this Activity.

Answer (score 1):

You could use [service binding](http://developer.android.com/guide/components/bound-services.html) so that only your topmost activity binds to the service.

Comment: I am not using service so far in my application. Do I need to use that just for this ?

Comment: Sorry, I thought the background thread that talks with the server was implemented as a service, but if not, I would not recommend implementing service just for this.